# how to set focus row on XtraGridControl Devexpress?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a list items to show on XtraGridControl. I want first item of the grid controll, which is always chosen when I sort by any column. I tried to find and use FocusedRowHandle property, but there is not.

What properties I can use to focus the first item on XtraGridControl programly?

Thanks advance.

Comment: `gridView1.FocusedRowHandle = 0;`

Comment: XtraGridControl has not FocusedRowHandle property :(

Comment: Try `gridControl.MainView.FocusedRowHandle = 0;`.

Comment: gridControl.MainView has focus attribute, not FocusedRowHandle :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve the problem myself by using ColumnView as code below:

```
ColumnView cv = m_wndGridCtrl.MainView as ColumnView;
cv.FocusedRowHandle = 0;
```

Thanks for your time supporting.